# React Component not support lifecycle methods?

Tags: reactjs

How can I use a lifecycle method such as ComponentDidMount inside a function below?

```
var React = require('react');

module.exports = function SectionalSquareComponent(props) {


  return (
    <div .....
```

Comment: lifecycles are parts of components/classes, not functional components

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [ReactJS lifecycle method inside a functional Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44506207/reactjs-lifecycle-method-inside-a-functional-component/44506265#44506265)

Answer (score 2):

You need to extend the React.Component class if you want to use the lifecycle function. As @xadm mentioned, you cannot use a functional component and lifecycle hooks.

Using the ES5 syntax as in your question, this could look like:

```
var createReactClass = require('create-react-class');
module.exports = createReactClass({
  componentDidUpdate: function(prevProps, prevState) {
  },
  render: function() {
    return (<div>...</div>);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said you need to use [react.component](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html) if you want to hook into lifecycle methods.

An interesting alternative, if you are completely focussed on functional components, is to use [recompose.lifecycle](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/docs/API.md#lifecycle) method, so you can do (from docs):

```
    const PostsList = ({ posts }) => (
      <ul>{posts.map(p => <li>{p.title}</li>)}</ul>
    )

    const PostsListWithData = lifecycle({
      componentDidMount() {
        fetchPosts().then(posts => {
          this.setState({ posts });
        })
      }

})(PostsList);
```

Comment: Why would you import an extra dependency to achieve this instead of following the React "way" of having stateful/class components hook into lifecycle methods and stateless/functional components not?

Comment: You wouldn't, it's just an interesting alternative and relatively useful library