# Where should I utilize useEffect in my HOC which is receiving props in React?

Tags: reactjs, state, higher-order-functions, high-order-component, react-lifecycle-hooks

I have this higher order function:

Its a supposed to render a  based on some props which I am using in conditionals to render my element.

```
function GenericIsUserLoggedInLink({ isLoggedIn, logOutUser, route, anchorText }) {
 if (isLoggedIn) {
  if (anchorText === undefined) {
   return <Link href="/"><a onClick={() => logOutUser()}>Log out!</a></Link>
  } else if (anchorText) {
   return <Link href={route}><a>{anchorText}</a></Link>
  } else {
   return null
  }
 } else {
  return  <Link href="/login"><a>Log in!</a></Link>
 }
}
```

It's getting props from a *[Parent class Component](https://github.com/antonioOrtiz/hillfinder/blob/hillfinder-with-redux-thunk/components/Home/Home.jsx), which is getting those props from the redux store.

*link to my repo to checkout the whole file

The above HOC is almost perfect but seems to bork when one tries to log-out for some reason I get this behavior on the left links in the nav.

[image]

I began to think maybe the problem is due to the re-rendering and I am not doing anything about it.

I learned recently in a class Component you'd utilized the `componentDidUpdate` life cycle method when something is changing in the component.

SO I did some digging ad found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44506207/reactjs-lifecycle-method-inside-a-functional-component#answers) regarding the methods one should use in a HOC. My question is where should it go?

I actually thought of something like this, but it didn't work...

import React, {  useEffect } from 'react';

```
function GenericIsUserLoggedInLink({ isLoggedIn, logOutUser, route, anchorText }) {
 if (isLoggedIn) {
  if (anchorText === undefined) {
   return <Link href="/"><a onClick={() => logOutUser()}>Log out!</a></Link>
  } else if (anchorText) {
   return <Link href={useEffect(() => {
 {route} // Just took a stab, on second blush I thought it wasn't that crazy!!
```

}, [route]);}>{anchorText}
      } else {
       return null
      }
     } else {
      return  Log in!
     }
    }

Anyway, I'd just like some insight as to why when you click the logout button the other nav links say login too...

Comment: It seems to be doing doing exactly what you asked it to, pls detail what behavior you are not expecting

Comment: @Drax ah sorry got carried away there...I updated the question.

Comment: Try adding a unique `key` prop to each of your link components in the conditional.

Answer (score 0):

In your [linked code](https://github.com/antonioOrtiz/hillfinder/blob/hillfinder-with-redux-thunk/components/Home/Home.jsx) you are using your HOC on your left nav links including your links "Profile" and "Dashboard" and inside your HOC the main condition is:

```
if (isLoggedIn) {
  ...
} else {
  return  <Link href="/login"><a>Log in!</a></Link>
}
```

So if you are not logged in (`isLoggedin === false`) you return a `Link` with "Log in!" written inside, and that's what get rendered instead of your navlink.
It doesn't have much to do with anything else mentioned.