# How to detect that a component will be updated with react hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

React hooks provides the possibility of mimicking the lifecycle method `componentDidUpdate` with `useEffect` without dependencies:

```
useEffect(() => {
   // componentDidUpdate
});
```

How can I detect if some prop is GOING TO update with react hooks?

I need to execute some code right before some changes.

Answer (score 2):

useEffect without a dependency will be called whenever the component re-renders. This is like a combination of `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate`

However if you wish to track a specific prop change, you can add that to the [`dependency array of useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects)

```
useEffect(() => {
   // called on change of props.somename as well as initial render
}, [props.somename]);
```

Also check the below posts for more details on emulating lifecycle methods with useEffect as well as executing useEffect only on update

[React hooks useEffect only on update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55075604/react-hooks-useeffect-only-on-update/55075818#55075818)

[ReactJS lifecycle method inside a function Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44506207/reactjs-lifecycle-method-inside-a-function-component/44506265#44506265)

P.S. You can add more than one value to the dependency array depending on your requirement

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to mimic the behaviour of `componentWillReceiveProps` you can easily put your logic inside the main body of the component:

```
function MyComponent(props) {
  // do stuff with props (it's like componentWillReceiveProps)
  return (...);
}
```

You don't need hooks for that.

Keep in mind that useEffect runs *after* your component was rendered with those props and not *before*.

`newProps -> MyComponent is called -> DOM updated -> useEffect called`