# React Functional Component: how to use componentDidMount()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function which is technically a React Functional Component:

```js
export default function Daw() {
  return (
    <>
        <div>Hello world.</div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Of course, my ordinary function cannot have the ReactJS method of `componentDidMount()`. Since it is not a class which extends `React.PureComponent`.

I'm using this function inside a ReactJS web app.

```js
export default function Daw() {

  componentDidMount() { // ** Cannot use this ReactJS method!?
  }

  return (
    <>
        <div>Hello world.</div>
    </>
  );
}
```

## Question

How can I possibly call `componentDidMount()` method of ReactJS inside my ordinary function? Is there a way to do it, without converting my function to a class which extends `React.PureComponent`? Is it possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're going to need React Hooks! All life-cycle methods we were doing in class components are available in functional components too via React Hooks, even in a better way. Read more about React hooks here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

And in this case, the equivalent of componentDidMount is this:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react'

export default function Daw() {
  useEffect(() => {
    // Code here will run just like componentDidMount
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
        <div>Hello world.</div>
    </>
  )
}
```

You can also learn about Effects in React by reading my article: [A Beginner’s Guide to Effects in React](https://ilxanlar.medium.com/a-beginners-guide-to-effects-in-react-b7440a596471)

Answer (score 13):

First import useEffect from react

`import { useEffect } from "react";`

Then use useEffect with an empty dependency array,it is same as componentDidMount()

`useEffect(() => { console.log("Mounted"); },[]);`

Refer react official documentation for learning all lifecycle methods using useEffect hook:- https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: that's not componentDidMount, but componentWillMount, for componentDidMount two hooks are required instead one

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use `componentDidMount()` (class lifecycle methods) in React functional components. Instead you can use useEffect hook to perform the same operation. Like this:

```
useEffect(() => {

}, []);
```

Check here for more info - [Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44506207/reactjs-lifecycle-method-inside-a-function-component)

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can use `useEffect` hook.
`useEffect` has the following abilities of class methods .i.e. `componentDidMount`, `componentDidUpdate` and `componentWillUnmoun`.

refer following info from official doc:
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html